# How to Configure Bamboo to Build NUnit Tests?

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration, nunit, bamboo

I am working on setting a project to use [bamboo](/questions/tagged/bamboo) for CI testing, but have hit a hitch when attempting to compile unit tests.  We are using the `.NET framework 4.5` and `NUnit v2.6.3.13283`.  When I am in [bamboo](/questions/tagged/bamboo), I have set up the specific job to check out the source code when a new commit is pushed, and then use `MSBuild` to build the code.  Unfortunately, when it reaches this second step, it decides that it no longer understands what `NUnit` is.

I have the `nunit.framework.dll` in the same directory (bin\Debug) as the class .dll, so I'm definitely confused as to how I should go about having `MSBuild` work out building the `NUnit` tests.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**  Error log for those not faint of heart.

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig
>   /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU /errorreport:prompt
>   /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE
>   /reference:c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll
>   /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll
>   /reference:"C:\build-dir\UCL-UNL-JOB1\Unit Class
>   Library\bin\Debug\Unit Class Library.dll" /debug+ /debug:full
>   /filealign:512 /optimize-
>   /out:obj\Debug\UnitClassLibraryNUnitTests.dll /target:library
>   AngleNUnitTests.cs 
>   "C:\Users\Bamboo\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>
> AngleNUnitTests.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>   [C:\build-dir\UCL-UNL-JOB1\UnitClassLibraryNUnitTests\UnitClassLibraryNUnitTests.csproj]
>
> AngleNUnitTests.cs(12,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'Test' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>   [C:\build-dir\UCL-UNL-JOB1\UnitClassLibraryNUnitTests\UnitClassLibraryNUnitTests.csproj]

etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a previous task to MSBuild one (Maybe you could consider to use the VisualStudio Task it works like a charm).

This previous task is a Command Task, it will update the Dlls related to the NuGet Package, in order to achieve it:

1. Create a New Executable on Bamboo, pointing to the nuget.exe file (if you don't have it you could download from https://www.nuget.org/
2. Create a New Command Task with the executable your created on the previous step.
3. On the Argument field: "restore YourSolution.sln"

In my approach I am using a VisualStudio task and after this one a MSTest Runner task.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using NuGet?
If so, you need to enable NuGet Package restore, because MSBuild does not know how to resolve these NuGet packages. This will create a .nuget directory in your solution which needs to be pushed the repository bamboo uses for the build.

Second problem I encountered when configuring the NUnit test runner with bamboo: the nunit-console.exe uses .NET Framework 3.5 which was not installed on my build server.

Answer (score 0):

When using Nuget with a source code repository, you have a couple of options.

1) check in your nuget executable to source code and create a bamboo command task that calls that location relative to the build directory, ${bamboo.build.working.directory}\tools\Nuget.exe.

2) Install the Nuget exe directly on the build server. Then you can create a new executable on Bamboo that you can reference in any task.

To create a new executable for use in tasks, use this - https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Defining+a+new+executable+capability